# Sqlserver watch for time change

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with a field called lock which will lock users from making changes to their data, this lock can be activated at various points throughout the app I am designing, however I have another column which means cut off date, basically the data can be changed between two dates. The start date is when the admins decide to open it out to everyone. I was wondering instead of using jobs, or a service is there a way to make sql server check its time against the cut of date time and mark the flag locked automatically. Almost like a file system watcher for sql server, baring in mind that I will have quite a few records all with different cut off dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a job to do it with the existing schema either using a SQL Server Job or a Windows Service.

If you can change your table structure, you can add a `Computed` column in the table which will lock the row based on both the existing lock and also based on the cut-off date logic. You will not be able to `index` this new computed column as it uses `GETDATE()`. To know more on computed columns, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191250%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

In this schema you will have to

1. update the original lock column for manual locking
2. refer to the new lock column to check if a row is locked

To create a computed column, you can try something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    dataid int identity(1,1) primary key,
    value VARCHAR(30),
    startdate date,
    cutoffdate date,
    old_lock bit,
    lock as ( CASE WHEN (cutoffdate <= GETDATE()) OR old_lock = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)

INSERT INTO data values('row lock by manual lock','2010-01-01','2099-01-01',1),
('row lock by auto lock','2010-01-01','2010-01-02',0),
('row unlocked','2010-01-01','2099-01-01',0),
('row locked','2010-01-01','2011-01-01',1)

SELECT * FROM data;
```

Comment: Hi thanks don't know why I didn't think of the computed column, will try that